# How do I define/change BigCommerce's rel canonical link functionality?

Tags: bigcommerce, canonical-link

Currently BigCommerce does a pretty good job at defining the canonical link for pages. But I am looking to update the behaviour for product list pages and remove the page number out of the link.

Currently it behaves as /category/?page=1, /category/?page2, and so on. I wish to elimate the page number completely and simple use /category

I prefer that search engines view all these pages as a single page as it is just the same data that is indexed from other places.

Currently the page defines the canonical link in the header as:

%%Page.CanonicalLink%%

I am looking to see if anyone has encountered this problem and is looking for a solution.

Thanks

Comment: BigCommerce there are canonical links setup for products, categories and brands, but none for the home page. I am little worry how to fix this?

Comment: I have same problem have you found any solution on that issue. If yes than can you suggest me so i can apply it for my BC store

Comment: I'm also looking to change `%%Page.CanonicalLink%%`, BigCommerce is stupid about controlling things like that.

Comment: Canonical link tag discussion with BigCommerce staff on BigCommerce forum here -- https://forum.bigcommerce.com/f10/pagination-and-canonical-urls-21494/index2.html